# Mongo find id with req.query.id node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

Im trying to get the id from the url with req.query.id(I've also used req.body)but it return an empty array but if I put the variable with number one I get the array with data.`

```
router.get('/:id', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    let id = req.query.id;
    db.collection("restaurant").find( { _id : id } ).toArray(function (err, result) {
      console.log(result);
      res.render('menu', {  restaurant: result });
});
  });
});
```

`

Comment: <a href="/menu/{{_id}}">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.query` is use to get the querystring part of the url after the `?` [querystrings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). What you should use in getting the value of `id` is `req.params`

```
const { id } = req.params;
```

and also you have to convert `id` to a number your mongodb `match` query will be

```
{ _id: Number(id) }
```

Comment: still gives empty array

Comment: what is the value of `_id` in your html

Comment: in the html the value is 1

Comment: is it the `result` variable that is an empty array ?